# How would PostgreSQL and Oracle behave for a query like SELECT * WHERE id='1blah'?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle, postgresql

On MySQL if I run a query

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = '1blah'
```

and there is a record where the ID is 1, the query will actually return that record. I am executing the query via Workbench and PHP/Doctrine, and I get the same result.

Why does MySQL does that? Is there a more general database concept involved here I am missing? Does the language/client play any role on this ?

And finally, how would PostgreSQL and Oracle behave ?

Comment: Aren't you missing the `FROM` clause?

Comment: The fully correct clause is irrelevant to my question, only the WHERE ID='1blah' matters, will add it anyhow for completeness.

Comment: You can use sqlfiddle to check it: [MySql](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ef285b/1), [oracle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/45daf/1), [SqlServer](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/372a0/1) and [postgresSQL](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/9c3eb/1)

Comment: Good one A.B.Cade. thank you.

Comment: Worse still, if you have an id of 0 in your table, "select * from table where id = 'banana'" will find it. oh, MySQL...

Answer (score 5):

Postgres and Oracle would (correctly) return a syntax error:

```
# select 1 = '1abc';
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "1abc"
LINE 1: select 1 = '1abc';
```

MySQL allows this because it does implicit conversion. Think of it as technical debt dating all the way back to its first versions. It allows (for instance) PHP apps to do a query like `select * from foo where id = '1'`. For better or worse.

If you dislike the behavior, you can disable it by making MySQL run in strict mode since MySQL 5. But this will break most PHP apps in the wild.

Comment: Actually you can do `select * from foo where id='1'` in PostgreSQL, Oracle and any other database known to me - nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 3):

MySQL operates in a non-strict mode by default which is why you're seeing this behavior. Essentially the default mode will do conversions to make the users life easier. Unfortunately I have found it makes your life more difficult when trying to debug.

To make MySQL behave like a traditional database server enable `TRADITIONAL` mode by executing `SET sql_mode=TRADITIONAL;`

This will enable data checking, null checks, division by zero checks and others.

See [here](http://www.mysqlfaqs.net/mysql-faqs/Client-Server-Commands/What-is-sql-mode-in-MySQL-and-how-can-we-set-it) and the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_traditional) for more information.

As Denis stated, PostgreSQL and Oracle will return an error if your ID is an integer column, or if ID is text (or a text variant) any row that matches that criteria, which is what it seems like you're expecting, and IMO what should occur by default.